# Local linearization in 3D and differentiability and continuity for multivariable functions

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

So, suppose we have some function $f(x): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

It's obvious that any differentiable function is also continuous. Also, $f(x)$ is differentiable only if $\lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}}$ exist.

In other words, the curve near ($h \rightarrow 0$) the point $(x_0, f(x_0))$ can be aproximated good as we want with some streight line with slope of $f'(x_0)$.

This is all good, but I have troubles understanding or seeing exact analogy in 3D.

1. How exatly can we approximate the surface (with infinitesimally small error) in 3D and why is that approximation a plane? I can, in some sense, see that the surface, if continuous, must be locally flat (for example, graph of parabola $y = x^2$ shifted in space) but I just don't know the proof.
2. What is condition that the surface given by $f(x, y)$ is continuous (what that even mean for 3D?) and (or) differentiable (what that even mean for 3D?).

Comment: 1. the approximation of a SURFACE (not a curve) is a plane

Comment: Thanks, @Nick. EDITED

Comment: 2. See wikipedia for the definition of differentiability:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions

Comment: I just started to learn linear algebra so I don't understand the article...

Answer (score 1):

For question #2:

To say that $z=f(x,y)$ is **continuous** at a point $(x_0,y_0)$ means that for *any* curve $(x(t),y(t))$ which passes through the point $(x_0,y_0)$ at $t=0$, we have
$$ \lim_{t \to 0} f(x(t),y(t)) = f(x_0,y_0) $$

Before saying what it means for $z=f(x,y)$ to be **differentiable**, think back to the 1-variable case. It means that the function $y=f(x)$ can be approximated by the tangent line. This means that
$$ \Delta y \approx f'(x_0) \Delta x $$
when $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ are very small. More technically, it means
$$ \Delta y = f'(x_0) \Delta x + \varepsilon \Delta x $$
where $\lim\limits_{\Delta x \to 0} \varepsilon = 0$. Similarly, the function $z = f(x,y)$ is differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$ if
$$ \Delta z \approx \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0) \Delta x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0) \Delta y $$
when $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ are both very small.
The more technical version is that
$$ \Delta z = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0) \Delta x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0) \Delta y + \varepsilon_1 \Delta x + \varepsilon_2 \Delta y$$
Where $\varepsilon_1$ and $\varepsilon_2$ go to zero as $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ go to zero.